# Libgdx - Change button's text label position if button is held down

Tags: android, user-interface, button, libgdx

I want to have a button with a 3D effect, so if you press it, it looks like the button is literally pressed down (inside the 'ground').

Like this:
[image]

But i want to save file size and only save the background texture without the text on it. So i am using TextButtons and tried to detect if the button is 'held down' like this:

```
    tbs1 = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    tbs1.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(Game.res.getAtlas("buttons_3").findRegion("button3_green_normal"));
    tbs1.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(Game.res.getAtlas("buttons_3").findRegion("button3_green_pressed"));
    tbs1.font = FontManager.bignoodle_90;
    quickMatchButton = new TextButton("Quick Match", tbs1);
    quickMatchButton.getLabelCell().padBottom(ASR.h(50));
    quickMatchButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            Game.gsm.setState(Game.gsm.CONFIGUREMATCH);
        }
    });
    quickMatchButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
            //This is not working!
            quickMatchButton.getLabelCell().padBottom(ASR.h(100));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The problem is that (i think) i can't change the position of the Text Label inside the button after i added the button to my layout table.

So main question: **How can i change the position (or the padding) of the TextLabel inside my button, after i created the button?**

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
tbs1.pressedOffsetY = -3;
```

this works for ImapgeButton, as pressedOffsetY belongs to ButtonStyle, it should work with text buttons too.

Comment: I just tried and it worked, can you show wat you did?